# Copy data from Lookup field to Filtered Lookup

Tags: lookup-column

I'm migrating a list up a level from the site to the site collection. After migrating the list via list template, I need to move the data from the Lookup to the new Filtered lookup field on the same list. (so I can delete the original list).

When trying to copy/paste the date in datasheet view, I found that it's a read only field. Is there a way to do this with just COTS abilities?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "filtered" lookup?

Comment: a filtered lookup as in a lookup column that is able to search the entire site collection for information, and not only the current site

Comment: Maybe you'll need to be more specific in your question. It seems that you are using a third party tool, not an out of the box feature.

Comment: Copy/Paste from when creating a new column for a List
 
  Lookup (information already on this site) 
  Filtered Lookup (Information from all sites in site collection

Comment: I'm sure copying the information between two standard lookup columns would also work for coping from a lookup to a filtered lookup. I am using SharePoint 2010, I don't have experience with older versions, so a filtered lookup could be a new feature?

Comment: @Christophe, thanks, so you're saying that it isn't possible to just move the data to the new column? A filtered lookup is just a column type........

Comment: see my answer below. Right, some columns have validation rules that are different depending on the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by filtered lookup. But keep in mind that a regular lookup field is actually a combination of an id and text. For example:
35;#LookupText#

The id is the most important part, this is what will allow your lookup to stay connected if you later edit the text.

The association of id (35) and value (LookupText) is specific to the source list, and probably doesn't match what your site collection filtered lookup expects.

Comment: Thanks, thankfully there isn't tooooo much data to just do the migration manually